# modificar array php

Tags: php

Tengo un array $array = [0,1];  donde 0 es libre, 1 es ocupado.

La idea es ir agregando el valor 1(ocupado) al array pero si encuentra un 0 lo reemplazaría y no debería agregarse ningún elemento. Por ejemplo, la primer vez que intento agregar un 1, debería reemplazar el valor de $array[0] por un 1. La siguiente ya que no hay mas 0("libre") se agrega un elemento -> array[2]=1 entonces quedaría: $array = [1,1,1], hasta tener 14 elementos.
El problema que tengo es que al agregar/reemplazar elementos en un bucle no puedo controlar que solo se agregue/reemplace 1 sola vez...

Todo esto lo manejo con un formulario , en cada cada click se intenta ocupar un lugar libre:

if ($tipoPlaza == 'grande' && count($array)<14){

```
   foreach($array as $valor){

        if($valor === 0){

            $array[$valor]=1;
            echo 'Se ocupa un lugar vacío ';

        }else{                 //si no es 0 será 1, por lo tanto se debe agregar un valor al array

            array_push($array,1);
          
            echo 'Se agrega un elemento ya que no hay libres';
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías, simplemente, usar la función [`array_search( )`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php); devuelve el índice dentro del *array* del primer elemento con el valor indicado, o `false` si no lo encuentra:

```
if( ( $tipoPlaza == 'grande' ) && ( count( $array ) < 14 ) ) {
    $index = array_search( 0, $array, true );

    if( $index !== false ) {
        $array[$index] = 1;
    } else {
        $array[] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que en el _else_ debería ser `$array[] = 1;`. Buena respuesta, +1 por la explicación y enlace a documentación.

Comment: @Triby Gracias. Cierto, se me liaron los dedos. Bien visto. Corregido.

Comment: Excelente, gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que solo se ejecute una sola vez en tu bucle usa `break` y/o `continue` cuando quieras seguir evaluando tu bucle.

- `break` hace que el bucle finalize y salga, sin esperar a que terminen todas las iteraciones.
- `continue` se salta el resto de la iteración y empieza la siguiente.

En tu caso, querrás un `break`:

```
foreach($array as $valor){
    if($valor === 0){
        array[$valor]=1;
        echo 'Se ocupa un lugar vacío ';
        break; // Después de sustituir el 0, salimos del bucle.
    }
    else { //si no es 0 será 1, por lo tanto se debe agregar un valor al array
        array_push($array,1);
        echo 'Se agrega un elemento ya que no hay libres';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, Fernando. Lo mejor en estos casos es dar un ejemplo al usuario preferiblemente con código además de la explicación del porqué.

Comment: gracias @Adrián, lo tomaré en cuenta en mis próximos comentarios, soy nuevo en stackoverflow así que hay mucho que aprender.